# Update column by picking a random element of given set - MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a query like this:

```
UPDATE cars SET color = "random-element"
```

where random-element is randomly picked out of a set, say
    {red, blue, green, orange, teal, shit, violet, black}

I want to update the color of each row with one of those colors.

Comment: @juergen I could not format the question like that even after indenting 4 spaces. :/

Comment: You need an empty line before ther code.

Comment: Oh.. Thats right. Thanks. Any luck with the solution?

Answer (score 0):

```
update cars
join
(
  select id from cars
  cross join 
  ( 
    select 'red' as c
    union all 
    select 'blue'
    union all
    select 'green'
  ) colors
  order by rand()
) tmp on cars.id = tmp.id
set color = tmp.c
```

Comment: I gor this error: 
Error Code: 1221. Incorrect usage of UPDATE and ORDER BY